# ROS navigation to obstacle

Tags: navigation, ros-noetic

When the goal point is designated as an obstacle area, the global planner cannot navigate.
Can you make the Global Planner move as close to the obstacle area as possible?

https://wiki.ros.org/global_planner
I can't find the relevant parameters in global_planner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the link you provided, there's the next parameter:

> /default_tolerance (double, default: 0.0)
> A tolerance on the goal point for the planner. The planner will attempt to create a plan that is as close to the specified goal as possible but no further than default_tolerance away.

If you mean that the planner isn't able to make a plan to a point inside an obstacle, this parameter should fix this.

Comment: If you found useful my answer I would encourage you to select it as an answer.

Comment: I solve this problem using navfn. but global planner default_tolerance is not working.
I asked a question because I encountered a problem while using explore_lite. Do you happen to know why explore_lite doesn't reach the last marker and stops?
I don't think it's a problem that Global Planner can't navigate.

Comment: My apologies, but I have no experience with that package. Global Planner isn't used to navigate, it is the local one who makes the robot travel through the plan. It could be interesting to try using the service to plan a path, and see if it is able to generate it (not the same as asking a goal). Which local planner did you use?

Comment: I use teb_local_planner. I think explore_lite automatically stops at the end of its exploration. I don't know where you get the information about explore_lite status.